# Test a method which accepts InputStream using Mockito

Tags: mockito, inputstream, junit5, java-11

Currently, I am migrating Powermockito to Mockito (Junit 5).
I need to test a method which accepts an InputStream. PFB code snippet:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class  TestClass{

mock creation
setup method

@Test
void testMethod(){
  InputStream inputStream = IOUtils.toInputStream("test data");

  injectMockObj.methodToTest(inputStream, "abc.xlsx");

  }
}

void methodToTest (InputStream inputStream, String name){

}
```

In above code, inputStream is passed as null and throwing NullPointerException from methodToTest.

Please advice how shall I pass non null InputStream to test full method

Comment: Wouldn’t it make more sense to invoke the code you want to test, instead of a mock?